# Link HTML file outside its folder

Tags: javascript, html

I have a folder named `"myWebsite"`.
Inside that folder I have `"index.html"` and another folder named `"other"`. Inside `"other"` I have CSS files JS files and `"page2.html"`. I have linked all files with my `"index.html"`. But when I am in `"page2.html"`, I want a link that will lead me to `"index.html"`.

`<a href=".../index.html">go back</a>`

Comment: From `index` you can use `other/page2.html` >> In `page2` you will use `../` to step out of the other folder like that `../index.html`

Comment: why are you putting your index.html inside a folder? usually you use a href="/" to go back to homepage or /index.html or whatever home page. unless you are still testing while its live you can do that im not sure where your myWebsite folder but this are ways its either ./index.html or what @MohamedEL-Gendy answer ../index.html or ../../index.html try this options.

Comment: Thanks guys. I understood now. I am new in this field so don't know much. I have Googled my question but couldn't find any solution. From there I found out that I can ask any coding related questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to navigate back you should use **'../'** if you want point two folders back you can use **'../../'** for instance.

In this case, within Page2.html use:

```
<a href="../index.html">go back<a>
```

NOTE: You have an extra dot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, this should fix it:

```html
<a href="../index.html">link</a>
```

The `../` directory references the parent directory.

**Examples:**

`<a href="sample.html">`    The *"sample.html"* file is located in the same folder as the current page.

`<a href="pages/sample.html">`  The *"sample.html"* file is located in the pages folder in the current folder.

`<a href="/pages/sample.html">` The *"sample.html"* file is located in the pages folder at the root of the current web.

`<a href="../sample.html">` The "sample.html" file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder.

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for more on HTML filepaths.